# Drawing a perfect circle in canvas with large lineWidth in chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am drawing a circle (r = 100px and lineWidth of 500 px ) in HTML canvas, using the method .arc of canvas API for a google chrome app.

But because of the large lineWidth the inaccuracies in the circle are enlarged, and it doesn't looks like a circle anymore.

Here is a demo <strike>http://jsbin.com/ufofor/1/edit</strike>  
 http://jsbin.com/ufofor/30/edit

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var g = c.getContext("2d");    
var r = 100;   

g.lineWidth = 500;    
g.arc(505, 505, r,0,2*Math.PI, true);
g.stroke();
```

Is there any way/hack to make a perfect circle , with a large lineWidth in canvas , using .arc method or any other ?

---

EDIT

The demo works fine in firefox, but in chrome you will find irregularities in the generated circle.

[Chrome screenshot of demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1YoJ.png)

[Firefox screenshot of demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rzbO.png)

Thanks @Felix for pointing this out.

Comment: I don't see how that is supposed to be a circle. Or do you want to draw a [circle sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector)?

Comment: No it is actually a circle, not a sector.

Comment: remove line g.lineCap= 'square'; seems to do it

Comment: @QuentinUK , I was just experimenting with different lineCaps like square, butt and round but that doesn't do it.

Comment: A full circle can be created with `g.arc(505, 505, r2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);`. There are enough examples on SO, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111548/why-is-the-canvas-circle-not-looking-like-a-circle/14111597. The parameters of the `arc` method are : `arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Arcs.

Comment: So, what's the problem with the new demo? Looks like a circle to me...

Comment: @FelixKling Its not a perfect circle because of the large line width.

Comment: @Tomarinator: I assume you are using Chrome? I'm using Firefox and it looks pretty good in there. That's why I also didn't understand what you where talking about. But in Chrome it really looks a bit strange (just tested it).

Comment: @FelixKling Actually I am using this in a chrome app so I need to get this working in Chrome, I will just add this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your .arc code to the below creates a perfect circle - the inputs to the method seemed skewy :S

```
g.arc(505, 505, r2, 0, Math.PI / 360, true);
```

Comment: And even the `Math.PI / 360` makes no sense to me - as another commenter posted it seems to be `2 * Math.PI`

Comment: that just change the starting angle and ending angle of  the circle, but doesnt change the outer egde of the circle it still looks like its a multi-sided polygon.

Comment: @Tomarinator there is no such thing as a circle in computer science - all circles are multi sided polygons in reality as there is finite resolution and precision to be accurate

Comment: If there was a way to change the number of sides in that multi-sided polygon, a more perfect cirlce could be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `arc` is

```
arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
```

where both `startAngle` and `endAngle` are in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). So for a full circle, you want to draw from `0` to `Math.PI * 2` - I have no idea where you got those `30` from.

Also, you might want to try to `fill()` your path instead of `stroke()`ing it with that absurd line width - which, in combination with the odd `lineCap` and `lineJoin` values, is probably the reason for the misshaped result.

Answer (score 0):

"My own 2 cents" if someone is still needing such thing as a "strokeWidth" for the arc() function ;)

```js
// 10 is the strokeWidth for the arc()
for(var i=0; i<= 10; i++){
  context.arc(circleObj.center_x, circleObj.center_y, 50+i, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.stroke();
}
```

The above can even be used before a call to 'clip()' to be used as a mask ;p

Hoping it helped at least one needy soul .. ;)

BONUS ==> one of the things I'm working on which lead me here to solve your troubles as I ended mine :P

--> https://jsbin.com/xuvogoyizu/edit?js,output

Click & drag to control the position of this "strokeWidth-ed arc mask" ;)