# CSS3 Transitions not working on width and height of canvas element

Tags: html, css, canvas, css-transitions

I use firefox 24.0 for development purpose.

i have this element in my code

Unique Id

```
.t_Bubble > canvas:nth-child(1)
```

External HTML content

```
<canvas style="width: 50px; height: 73px;" height="73" width="50"></canvas>
```

it later changes to this HTML content in later part of code.

```
<canvas style="width: 114px; height: 62px;" height="62" width="114"></canvas>
```

i have applied this css on this element

```
.t_Bubble > canvas:nth-child(1){

transition: width 2s ease,height 2s linear;
-moz-transition:width 2s ease, height 2s linear;
-webkit-transition:width 2s ease, height 2s linear;
}
```

But no transition happens anytime in browser. Can you help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: I’m also using Firefox 24, and it works fine. Can you add [an example](http://codepen.io/pen), please?

Answer (score 2):

I just [**tried**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/kYRnG/2/) it, and it worked for me. So what I said is totally `wrong`.

So my guess will be that your CSS don't apply to the canvas, Due to an error in the selector.

can you share your HTML?

also, use `:first-child` instead of `:nth-child(1)` *it has better support*

<del>Transitions works when you change the `width` and `height` via different styling.

in example: you may have a different styling rule for `:hover` or `:active`.
then the transition will occur when you hover, and will be transition back to normal when you stop.
but not by applying direct width & height attributes to the DOM element.
that will kick in the change right away.

what is making the HTML to change? maybe you can apply a different class to the element instead of hard coding the changes into the DOM? that way you will benefit from the transition.

also, Your CSS rule overides this 'hard-coded' sizes,
you can see in that [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/kYRnG/) that the 200px is taken over the 100. so even after the DOM changes, it takes no affect, because the CSS rule still overrides it.</del>

Comment: @BoltClock its not via style, its hard-coded in the elements attributes.

Comment: My bad, I see now that the code includes both `style` and `width`/`height` attributes.

Comment: @avrahamcool hi, actually its one of jquery plugin for tooltip. Honestly i have no idea on whats going on inside. should i go with traditional javascript code to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I think that its always better to know what your using. especially if it don't gives you exactly what you want. If you can achieve the same thing.. on your own - it might be a better solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you're probably not targeting the canvas element properly with your CSS selector.

Long 'answer': I think there's a couple of things to note:

1. Changing the `height` or `width` attributes of the `canvas` tag will complete clear it (i.e. remove anything drawn to it, resetting it to a blank slate). (Although apparently, this doesn't happen in some browsers.)
2. For `<canvas>` elements, the `height` or `width` attributes have a unique relationship with the CSS properties of `height` and `width`, which I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079320/1937302
3. Changes to the `height` or `width` attributes **will not be** 'transitioned'/animated
4. Changes to the CSS properities of `height` or `width` attributes **will be** 'transitioned'/animated

I've demoed some of this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/WWtGZ/3/

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" height="50" width="100"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    height: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 30, 30);

// changing width attribute clears canvas element (in most broswers)
// changing width attribute isn't animated by CSS transition
setTimeout(function () {
    canvas.width = "200";
}, 2000);

// changing CSS rule for width is animated, although if no CSS rule for width already exists, then a width of 0px is taken as the starting point
setTimeout(function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 30, 30);
    canvas.style.width = "100px";
}, 4000);
```