# Me or jsfiddle bug?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, jsfiddle

Simple canvas drawing, seems like on jsFiddle coordinates are not being recognized correctly:
JS:

```
var w = $(".trace").width();
var h = $(".trace").height();

var bgCanvas = $("<canvas></canvas>").addClass("canvas");
bgCanvas.width(w).height(h);
var bgContext = bgCanvas[0].getContext("2d");

$(".trace").append(bgCanvas);

bgContext.strokeStyle = "#000";
bgContext.moveTo(0,0);
//this line should go to the middle of the canvas
//instead it goes much further both horizontally and vertically
bgContext.lineTo(200,100);
bgContext.stroke();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="trace"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.trace{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
.canvas{
    border: 1px #000 dotted;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj6cv/5/)

Checked on latest IE and Chrome.
They (jsFiddle developers) suggest to share and check with others before submitting an issue on github, so there... Is it my mistake somwhere, or is it jsFiddle?

Comment: [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with “width” / “height” properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties), [canvas width attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
bgCanvas.width(w).height(h);
```

to this and it will work:

```
bgCanvas.attr({width: w, height:h});
```

By using `.width` and `.height` you are simply modifying the CSS size of the canvas *element* not its bitmap. As the default size is 300 x 150 just just gets stretched to whatever you set with CSS.

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/mj6cv/8/)**

Comment: now this is odd... so it is jQuery then? for canvas we can't simply use $.width(), but instead go via attributes? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk not really jQuery's fault, it is setting the CSS dimension as expected but for canvas you need to explicitly set its width and height *attributes* which is not the same as the CSS equivalents.

Comment: yes, Andreas just posted a link in comments to my original post, describing the issue

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk In addition I [write a bit about setting canvas size here](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-properly-set-size-of-the-canvas-element/).