# why we can't set width and height for canvas using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

Why the canvas appears as scaled one, when the height and width is specified in css instead of DOM?

Html:

```
 <canvas></canvas>
```

Css:

```
 canvas{
       width:100px;
       height:100px;
    }
```

Comment: in which browser? On Chrome 38 and Firefox 32 your code works fine. (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wsIyp)

Comment: in chrome 27. i created canvas and setting width and height through css file

Comment: who didn't work on canvas don't put downvote. the question is good?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

You can set Width and Height on canvas using CSS - but,

canvas width,height attribute determines the actual pixel will be used to draw on canvas. It is used for canvas co-ordinate system.

On the other hand CSS width / height is related to box model.

By default the canvas usage 300px width and 150px height. If you set CSS width / height without setting canvas attributes that will be applied on that 300px/150px. Imagine a 300px/150px sized image where you are setting the width/height using CSS as 100px/100px. What will happen? it will distort right? same thing applied for canvas as well.

You'll find more details on HTML living standard page - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-canvas-width

Hope that answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

so think of the canvas element to be composed of two different view.

1. The html element(canvas).
2. The inner drawing surface of the canvas.

First approach:

Setting the height and width of the canvas through css will only set them to the html element canvas but not to the inner drawing surface(this is generally bad practise when it comes to canvas elements).

Now usually with this approach when the element width and height is more than the default width and height of the drawing surface, what the browser does is, it scales up the drawing surface to find the canvas element size. Hence you will notice the drawing surface zoomed in.

Second approach:

Setting the height and width of the canvas through the element width and height attributes, set them to both the canvas and the drawing surface. Like so,

```
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: look it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

`canvas` element has `height` and `width` attributes. Assign values through javascript code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
canvas.width  = 100;
canvas.height = 100;
```

As for your question, it's because the only thing that you resize through css is the "container" of the canvas, not the size of the canvas itself. When you try to draw on the canvas with the "container" size bigger than the size of the canvas itself the image will look blurry.

Comment: The OP ask why width and height not set for canvas using css?

Comment: @JqueryKing there I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way you have written. Have you checked if you have linked the CSS file correctly?

I usually add something like

```
border: 1px solid;
```

to my css to let me figure out the width and height. You can check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12351c6c/1/)

Comment: check with browser. while setting canvas width and height through css file code, the canvas rendering object seems scaling

Comment: @Collins - you draw line in canvas means it will not appear try it

Comment: I just checked, nothing seems to be wrong in chrome 39, firefox 34. Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/12351c6c/9/

Comment: @albertJegani I've explained that in my answer.