# Javascript canvas, drawing at wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am reading and printing the mouse coordinates correctly in my "mousePos" header  But when I draw on the canvas, using the same exact coordinates,  by clicking and dragging, I am drawing to far to the bottom and to far to the right.  I can fix this by not using style.canvas.width="512px", but then I can not set the size.  The size must be 512 by 512.

Any tips?

```js
    
        var resize =1;
        var mouseX, mouseY;
        var pen = "?";
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var fill = "#FF0000";  //Red
    
        canvas.style.width="512px";
        canvas.style.height="512px";
    
        menu.style.width="512";
        menu.style.height="512";
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", penDown);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", penUp);
    
        function mouseMove(event) {
            mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
            mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
            document.getElementById('mousePos').innerHTML = "Mouse Position: X" + mouseX + " Y" + mouseY;
    
            if(pen == "down") {
                ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 4, 4);
            }
        }
    
        function penDown() {
            pen = "down";
            //alert("pen = " + pen + " mouse pos:" + mouseX + "," + mouseY);
        }
    
        function penUp() {
            pen = "up";
           // alert("pen = " + pen + " mouse pos:" + mouseX + "," + mouseY);
        }
    
        function backGround() {
            //alert("Called backGround");
            canvas.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('BackGround').value;
        }
    
        function penColor(){
            //alert("Called penColor");
            fill = document.getElementById('PenColor').value;
            ctx.fillStyle = fill;
        }
    
        /*
    
            questions:
                Why is my pen not drawing at the mousepos?
    
                use addEventListener or onEvent?
    
                call script when body loads(onDOMcontentLoaded), or call function from script(onload="init()")
    
                Am I taking the right approach, or am I coding myself into a corner?
    
                Any other tips?
        */
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Canvas Test 3</title>
        <script>
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body bgcolor="#20b2aa">
    
    <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute;
             border: 2px solid black; background-color: white"
            onmousemove="mouseMove(event)">
    </canvas>
    
    <div id="menu" style="position: absolute; right: 20%;
                background-color: lightcoral; border: 2px solid black;">
        <p> Back Ground:
            <select id="BackGround" onchange="backGround();">
                <option value="white">white</option>
                <option value="black">black</option>
                <option value="red">red</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
                <option value="orange">orange</option>
                <option value="purple">purple</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Pen Color:
            <select id="PenColor" onchange="penColor()">
                <option value="#000000">black</option>
                <option value="#FFFFFF">white</option>
                <option value="#FF0000">red</option>
                <option value="#0000CC">blue</option>
                <option value="#006600">green</option>
                <option value="#FFFF00">yellow</option>
                <option value="#FF3300">orange</option>
                <option value="#990099">purple</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <h2 id="mousePos" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5%">Mouse Position | </h2>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you move your cursor towards the point where x and y are 0 (observing the coordinates desplayed in the header), where is that point? Is it at the left top corner of the page client area? Are ctx.canvas.offsetLeft and ctx.canvas.offsetTop correct?

Answer (score 14):

You have to add the attributes `width` and `height` to your canvas. These properties should be the same you set the respective css properties.

See [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties) for more information on this.

Change

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; border: 2px solid black; background-color: white" onmousemove="mouseMove(event)">
```

to

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512" style="position: absolute; border: 2px solid black; background-color: white" onmousemove="mouseMove(event)">
```

Comment: @RyanMiles If this answer solved your problem it would be nice if you accept it :) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: i have added position: relative; or position: absolute; is working for me. thanks.