# Rectangle not displaying in canvas when drawing with mouse events

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a rectangle with mouse events, it seems to work, I've used *console.log* in all my code to see what is happening, and is all running nice, but the rectangle just dislikes me I think, it doesn't appear!

I can't figure out how to find the mistake!

I only want a direction, thank you for your time.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lexpg6c8/)

And the code here:

```
$("body").wrapInner("<canvas id='myCanvas'>");
var canvas = $("#myCanvas").css("cursor", "crosshair");
var context = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
var div = {x:0, y:0};
var draw_rectangle = function(e){
    context.fillRect (
        div.x, div.y,
        (e.pageX - div.x),
        (e.pageY - div.y)
    );
};
context.fillStyle = "#aaf";
canvas.on("mousedown", function(e){
    div.x = e.pageX;
    div.y = e.pageY;
    canvas.on("mousemove", draw_rectangle);
});
canvas.on("mouseup", function(){
    canvas.off("mousemove");
    console.log("Drawed.");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, that the ``` css properties``height ``` and `width` are problematic with `canvas` elements, because they stretch your canvas element to fit the given size - stretching the `canvas'` bitmap. The `html properties` `height` and `width` on the other hand determine the size of your `canvas'` bitmap.

So, a solution in your case would be, to change your code to the following:

```js
$("body").wrapInner("<canvas id='myCanvas'>");
$('#myCanvas').attr("width", 400);
$('#myCanvas').attr("height", 500);
var canvas = $("#myCanvas").css("cursor", "crosshair");
var context = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
var div = {x:0, y:0};
var draw_rectangle = function(e){
    context.fillRect (
        div.x, div.y,
        (e.pageX - div.x),
        (e.pageY - div.y)
    );
};
context.fillStyle = "#aaf";
canvas.on("mousedown", function(e){
    div.x = e.pageX;
    div.y = e.pageY;
    canvas.on("mousemove", draw_rectangle);
});
canvas.on("mouseup", function(){
    canvas.off("mousemove");
    console.log("Drawed.");
});
```

```css
canvas {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Information Source: [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)