# Why is my canvas creating ellipses when I want to create circles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Everytime I try to make a circle by this method (where board is the canvas board which has the context of 2d):

```
        board.lineWidth = 4;
        board.beginPath();
        board.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 10,0,360);
        board.strokeStyle = "blue";
        board.stroke();
        board.closePath();
```

It always created more of a ellipse than a circle and it never go by the coordinates I give it. If I say canvas.width/2 and with height (to center it) it even goes outside the canvas itself. When I give it something else like 30 it goes much further than 30 pixels aswell.

Sidenote: My width and height of my canvas are both 500 pixels.

Comment: Last parameter should be float in radians, not degrees

Comment: Same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties

Comment: If your sizing the canvas with CSS--don't. Instead, resize using `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`.

Comment: It was because i sized it with css. Thank you very much! That helped me alot :)

Answer (score 1):

5th parameter of [`arc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) expected to be an angle in radians, not degrees.

`360 degrees = 2 * PI`

So you have to change your code to:

```
...
board.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
```

Comment: That's true, but I think a wrong angle would still produce a circle, not an ellipse.