# Canvas tag doesn't work if CSS formatting is used

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have created a simple web app using canvas HTML5 tag and JavaScript which allows to draw along the line mouse is moved while pressed. This works fine when I don't use any CSS formatting. However, when I use the CSS formatting, this doesn't work properly: the line is drawn far away from where the mouse is positioned.

```js
context = document.getElementById('drawing').getContext("2d");
//below code to ensure compatibility with older browser by check if addEventListener is available or not
var EventUtil = {
addHandler: function(element, type, handler){ if (element.addEventListener){
            element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
            } else if (element.attachEvent){
            element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
            } else {
            element['on' + type] = handler; }
            },

removeHandler: function(element, type, handler){ if (element.removeEventListener){
            element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
            } else if (element.detachEvent){
            element.detachEvent('on' + type, handler);
            } else {
            element['on' + type] = null; }
            }
} ;

//Drawing canvas related functions
var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}
function whenMousedown () {
        var mouseX = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
         paint = true;
         addClick(event.pageX - this.offsetLeft, event.pageY - this.offsetTop);
         redraw();
};
function whenMousemove (){
        if(paint){
          addClick(event.pageX - this.offsetLeft, event.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
          redraw();
        }
};

function whenMouseup(){
  paint = false;
};
function whenMouseleave(){
  paint = false;
};

function redraw(){
          context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

          context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
          context.lineJoin = "round";
          context.lineWidth = 5;

          for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
            context.beginPath();
            if(clickDrag[i] && i){
              context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
             }else{
               context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
             }
             context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
             context.closePath();
             context.stroke();
  }
}
// this clears the canvas and sets the arrays to null
function clearCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height) // Clears the canvas
  clickX = [];
  clickY = [];
  clickDrag = [];
};

EventUtil.addHandler (document.getElementById('drawing'), 'mousedown', whenMousedown);
EventUtil.addHandler (document.getElementById('drawing'), 'mousemove', whenMousemove);
EventUtil.addHandler (document.getElementById('drawing'), 'mouseup', whenMouseup);
EventUtil.addHandler (document.getElementById('drawing'), 'mouseleave', whenMouseleave);
EventUtil.addHandler(document.getElementById('clearBtn'), 'click', clearCanvas) ;
```

```css
#container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 605px;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
#body {
  margin: 10px;
 }
.heading {
  margin: auto;
  width: 455px;
    color: blue;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#drawing {
  width: 780px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: auto;
 }
#clearBtnDiv{
    margin: auto;
    width:80px;
}
#clearBtn{
    color: purple;
    font-size: large;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Drawing Canvas</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href = 'drawingMain.css'>

</head>
<body>
<div id = 'container'>
<div id='body'>
 <h1 class = 'heading'> Welcome to a Drawing Canvas!!</h1>
<canvas id ='drawing'  >
 A sample drawing <! this will be shown if canvas doesnt work in the browser !>
</canvas>
</div>
<div id ='clearBtnDiv'>
 <input type="submit" value="Clear" id ='clearBtn'  > </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src= 'drawing.js'> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code is @ github, so share it here please.

Comment: I found that it is not the CSS formatting, in general, which was causing this issue but this issue was specific to setting the **height** and **width** of the canvas property. These properties of canvas should be set in below manner:  canvasObject.setAttribute('width', '475'). Further, this has been well explained in another question: [Canvas is stretched when using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

Comment: This is very well answered! Thanks for the link! Totally ignored the h/w of canvas attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't have all the offsetParent elements offsetTop and offsetLeft computed. The offsetLeft/Top only returns the offset pixel of the left border to its first parent, but your #drawing canvas has #body and #container and  element as parents, when you set margin to center them, you need to also add these margin and border to the mouse event because you are using the page.x as the base.

Comment: I tried to remove the margins and padding, it didn't solve it. However, when I removed the below property from #drawing, it is not aligned properly but works as expected. 
  width: 780px;
  height: 500px;