# canvas background image is getting stretched

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, background

I want this image in my canvas but it is getting stretched and not fitting the box properly. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var img = new Image();
img.src = "my image url";

img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);   
}
```

Please check this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMZM2.png

What I want is my logo fit in the canvas box.

Here is my whole logo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jFjM.png

Comment: Only a part of the logo image is coming in canvas and not the whole logo.

Comment: You have to set canvas dimensions to image's counterparts before drawing in `onload` callback.

Comment: My canvas width is responsive... please check my app here: http://bit.ly/1SYiniX

Comment: if I do it like this:

Comment: img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width=489;
            canvas.height=244;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,489,244);

Comment: than my canvas will not remain responsive..

Comment: _If your renderings seem distorted, try specifying your width and height attributes explicitly in the `<canvas>` attributes, and not using CSS._ ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to your image to fit with in the canvas-

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight,x,y, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

where x and y is the top left position where you want to display your logo. imgWidth and imgHeight are the width and height of your logo respectively.

[image]

Refer this image. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/

Comment: tried this: ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,489,200,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Comment: but it is coming a blank space

Comment: I actually got it working, just facing a small issue. I have used this: ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); But my logo image is coming 300x150 only in any screen size. Can you help me why is it so?

Comment: user3657517 There are only two functions in context. ctx.drawImage(img,x,y) and ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw,sy, dx,dy,dw,dh); where s is source and d is destination

Comment: Instead use - ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,imgwidth,imgheight, 0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

Comment: when I alert my canvas width which is responsive with this: window.alert(canvas.width);   IT IS COMING 300 ONLY IN ALL THE SCREEN RESOLUTION, THAT'S WHY DRAW IMAGE IS TAKING 300 AS WIDTH.

Comment: logo image is displaying in 100% but it is taking 300 as canvas width only so that the image is getting stretched.

Comment: It will be stretched if you want it to fit the width but height remains same. You can do one thing center the logo and fill the canvas with the background color of your image.

Comment: I cant do that, I have to make it in full width, height will be ok if not fixed, but even after removing fixed heigh it is taking 300px canvas size only.

Comment: Can you please help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803418/not-able-to-download-final-merged-canvas