# Mouse pointer coordinates and canvas coordinates not matching

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a line using canvas. While drawing a line my mouse pointer coordinates and canvas coordinates are mismatching. If I drag mouse at top of my canvas it draws a line at bottom. Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong here. I tried the below example.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Shathiran/bpunb9dn/5/

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false, prevX = 0, currX = 0, prevY = 0, currY = 0, dot_flag = false;
 
     var x = "black", y = 2;
     
     function init() {
         canvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas');
         ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         w = ctx.clientWidth;
         h = ctx.clientHeight;
          
         canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
             findxy('move', e)
         }, false);
         canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
             findxy('down', e)
         }, false);
         canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
             findxy('up', e)
         }, false);
         canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
             findxy('out', e)
         }, false);
     }

     function draw() {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
         ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
         ctx.strokeStyle = x;
         ctx.lineWidth = y;
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.closePath();
     }
     
     function findxy(res, e) {
         if (res == 'down') {
             prevX = currX;
             prevY = currY;
             currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
             currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
     
             flag = true;
             dot_flag = true;
             if (dot_flag) {
                 ctx.beginPath();
                 ctx.fillStyle = x;
                 ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                 ctx.closePath();
                 dot_flag = false;
             }
         }
         if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
             flag = false;
         }
         if (res == 'move') {
             if (flag) {
                 prevX = currX;
                 prevY = currY;
                 currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                 currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                 draw();
             }
         }
     }
     init();
```

```html
<div class="paper">
    <canvas id="drawCanvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;border: 1px solid #000">     </canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the mouse positions fine. The problem here is how you are assigning the `width` and `height` of your canvas, mainly because you are setting it via CSS as a style (which "stretches" the canvas) other that the `width` and `height` attributes (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties) for more information). To fix this set your `width/height` as HTML attributes to your canvas.

For example:

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false, prevX = 0, currX = 0, prevY = 0, currY = 0, dot_flag = false;
 
     var x = "black", y = 2;
     
     function init() {
         canvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas');
            canvas.setAttribute('width', canvas.parentNode.offsetWidth);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', canvas.parentNode.offsetHeight);
         ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         w = ctx.clientWidth;
         h = ctx.clientHeight;
          
         canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
             findxy('move', e)
         }, false);
         canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
             findxy('down', e)
         }, false);
         canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
             findxy('up', e)
         }, false);
         canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
             findxy('out', e)
         }, false);
     }

     function draw() {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
         ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
         ctx.strokeStyle = x;
         ctx.lineWidth = y;
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.closePath();
     }
     
     function findxy(res, e) {
         if (res == 'down') {
             prevX = currX;
             prevY = currY;
                var cRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
             currX = e.clientX - cRect.offsetLeft;
             currY = e.clientY - cRect.offsetTop;
     
             flag = true;
             dot_flag = true;
             if (dot_flag) {
                 ctx.beginPath();
                 ctx.fillStyle = x;
                 ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                 ctx.closePath();
                 dot_flag = false;
             }
         }
         if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
             flag = false;
         }
         if (res == 'move') {
             if (flag) {
                 prevX = currX;
                 prevY = currY;
                 currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                 currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                 draw();
             }
         }
     }
     init();
```

```html
<div class="paper" width="400">
    <canvas id="drawCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid #000">     </canvas>
</div>
```

---

*Note* you can set the canvas height and width to 100% by using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. Although if you want it to dyncamically change you need to update it on resize:

```
canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: yes this works fine, but  I need to fix width and height of <canvas> to above <div>

Comment: is there any way to set canvas width height responsive with parent <div> tag.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva Yes you can set the width/height to that of the parent by doing: `canvas.setAttribute('width', canvas.parentNode.offsetWidth)`. I've added it in an edit.