# HTML Canvas scales along x axis? (Using Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas

I am drawing on a canvas object using JavaScript and somehow Internet Explorer (don't ask, I have to), Version 11 scales the drawings along the x axis.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();
```

You would expect a circle to appear. But instead I get an Ellipse:

[image]

(Don't mind the horizontal line on the left, that just the surrounding div. The canvas is the small square.)

**EDIT:** The size of the canvas is 100 x 100.

Comment: are you somehow setting some width or height with CSS on this poor canvas ? If so, stop right now and use its own `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: Only `width` and `height` attributes? Or are there any other attributes you have to set inside the html tag?

Comment: Just don't set it through CSS, at least until you understand what it does. Then you'll remember to always set it by respecting the aspect-ratio of your context. And no, no other attributes needed.

Comment: Can you explain what it does? I think I only set height and width of `div` Elements through CSS before...

Comment: [One of the many question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties), but without seeing your CSS, it's only a guess and can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments the answer is to set height and width of the `canvas` object as attributes of the canvas-tag. Like this:

```
<canvas height="200" width="400"></canvas>
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties) for further explanation.