# Dynamically locate button inside HTML <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Inside canvas I draw a line, that line will create dynamically. In the end of line, i want to create an HTML button. But I don't know how to create.
Plz, help  me.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas> 
<input id="btn" type="button">
```

**Javascript**

```
var line = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = line.getContext("2d");
document.getElementById("c").style.height = "300px";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 1, line.width, line.height);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


drawLine(20, 20, 150, 70); 

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var dx = x2 - x1,
        dy = y2 - y1,
        len = (Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)-1)|0,
        ang = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    ctx.translate(x1|0, y1|0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.drawImage(line, 0, 0, len, 1);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)
}
ctx.arc(20, 20, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.stroke();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tndmez4a/6/)

Comment: You'd have to float the button on top of the canvas

Comment: Also, you shouldn't resize a canvas through styling.

Comment: Why are you using `|`?

Comment: I am working on xamarin mobile app, there is a requirement to create the dynamic path from one location to another location. From xamarin it's not working then i follow this approach xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put or draw an HTML element *in* a canvas. You can create the button and then use `position: absolute` with the same `left` and `top` as the end of the line's `x` and `y`.

Take a look at this snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

drawLine(20, 20, 150, 70);
ctx.arc(20, 20, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var button = createButtonOnCanvas(x2, y2);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function createButtonOnCanvas(x, y) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  btn.style.position = "absolute";
  btn.style.left = x + "px";
  btn.style.top = y + "px";
  btn.innerHTML = "btn";

  return btn;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

Since you want to *create* a button, instead of moving an already existing one, I made a function that creates a completely new button and moves it over a certain `(x, y)` of the canvas.

You should also use the `lineTo()` method to draw a line and resize the canvas' `width` and `height` **attributes**. If the `width` and `height` attributes are `100` and `100` while the CSS `width` and `height` styles are `200px` and `200px`, those `100x100` pixels will be stretched to fill a `200x200` canvas and everything drawn will get blurry. For more information, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties) question.

Comment: _What_ isn't working properly? It draws a line on a canvas and puts a `<button>` over the end of it.

Comment: button not coming bottom of line. it comes in center.  https://jsfiddle.net/tndmez4a/9/

Comment: As I said in my answer, **don't resize the canvas using CSS**. Remove `width: 80%` from the CSS and it works as expected. Otherwise, the canvas is stretched and the button comes over the "unstretched" coordinate of the line.