# Determining whether or not Width/Height goes inside a Style Tag, or whether you leave it by itself as an HTML Attribute inside HTML?

Tags: html

I'm not just referring to image's so it's not a duplicate.

It could be Inline JavaScript, Div tags, the list goes on.

Just cause I mentioned width/height, doesn't automatically mean images.

**And I was primarily asking about 'HTML,' Not CSS***

Maybe I should've been more specific in asking my question.

**This Is My Question:**

What's the rule of thumb when determining whether or not Width/Height goes inside a **Style Tag**, or whether you leave it by itself as an **HTML Attribute** inside HTML.

**Input Variable**

```
<element width="100px" height="100px" />
```

**Style Tag**

```
<element style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
```

Comment: `<element width="100px" height="100px" />` I thought with this format, where it's valid, you don't use a unit, i.e. it would be `<element width="100" height="100" />` - nevermind, px is the `default`

Comment: width/height is only a valid attribute for `<canvas>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <object>, <video>`  - see [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

Comment: @Jaromanda X: You are correct. The unit must be left out. width="100px" height="100px" is not valid.

Comment: Because the width and height attributes assume pixels, you can't use these attributes to use em, percent, point, or any other non-pixel unit. If I remember correctly, you also can't use "auto" as a value.

Comment: "I'm not just referring to image's so it's not a duplicate." It doesn't matter. The element types to which this question even applies (namely, *not* div) to begin with all behave the same as img.

Comment: @BoltClock, you forgot an important one, yes not really part of HTML per se, but still often seen and valid in HTML docs (hint it's in OP's user name). And with the `<svg>` tag it does have a real importance to set it (same for `<canvas>` btw) since if not set, `width` will default to `300`, `height` to `150` and will have incidence on their inner doc/view.

Comment: @BoltClock - I read something that suggested otherwise, though I did think the statement was correct :p

Comment: @Jaromanda X: Browsers do just parse the values without the units, making it seem like it works, but that's about it.

Comment: Regarding your edit: setting it in a style attribute is setting it through CSS. I can give you a valid point to reopen your question: *On a `<canvas>` element it makes an [huge difference between setting it through attribute or through css.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)* Also, I would avoid the *What's the rule-of-thumb*  part since the answer is "There is none".

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use css for styling because

- After dynamic deployment of html, its little hesitating to access
  attribute of html.
- Sometimes as an Frontend developer you just have
  access to static code and in this way it is easy to manipulate the
  css code as compare to update html code

Answer (score -2):

**They have the same effect.**

`<element width="100px" height="100px" />` has been used for a long time, same with the widht/height properties of say.. an HTML table.

There is no difference whether you specify it on the element itself or within the CSS, though I now prefer using CSS so I can keep the HTML clear and concise.

**There is absolutely NO difference.**

Comment: I don't think `<element width="100px" height="100px" />` is valid. It should be `<element width="100" height="100">` The unit "px" is assumed for the width and height attributes. Therefore, you can't use non-pixel units like em, percent, or point.

Comment: Another difference is that the `width` and `height` attributes are only available on some elements, but I think width and height css property is available on any block level element.

Comment: `There is absolutely NO difference.` - absolutely wrong, given that it only works for a handful of elements

Comment: There are differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties

Comment: Wow.... So, what does that mean? I was only referring to inside HTML though.