# Draw path - canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

i want to draw a simple path in canvas like this:

[image: example]

i have allready tried (also im not sure how to create the point with a radius at 440, 400):

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(500, 0);
ctx.lineTo(440, 400);
ctx.lineTo(0, 500);
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
ctx.fill();
```

but it shows me just a black 600x600 rectangle
https://jsfiddle.net/aaroniker/pmgkymch/

Thanks!

Comment: use `ctx.stroke();`

Comment: I would recommend you to checkout this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp)

Comment: @darkangel does not work for me

Comment: @Ramesh thanks, but already did

Comment: short answer: using CSS to give height and width to your canvas makes the coordinate system wonky. long answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas elements contain rasterized pixel data for an image of the same dimensions as those of the canvas element's width and height attributes, which default to 300 and 150 respectively. Drawing to a canvas element uses pixel coordinates of the canvas unless a context drawing transform is in effect.

Setting width and height of a canvas element in CSS *scales* the canvas to the dimensions set in CSS when presenting it on screen. As with scaling an ordinary image element, canvas image quality can drop noticeably  if a small canvas is scaled to too large a size.

**Answer A**

You are seeing a black square because you drew onto a 300 x 150 pixel canvas using 600 x 600 coordinates. Filling the oversized path drawn filled in all the actual canvas pixels. The 300 x 150 pixel canvas was presented as a 600 x 600 screen area due to CSS scaling.

**Answer B**

The context's path drawing `arcto` method is used to create a rounded corner but you don't need to work out where it leaves the drawing position provided you continue by drawing a line to a known point.

In this example I've set the canvas element dimensions in HTML to 600 x 600, and scaled it to a different size (150px x 150px) in CSS

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius = 100; // a number
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(500, 0);
    ctx.arcTo( 440, 400, 0, 500, radius) 
    ctx.lineTo( 0, 500); // join end of arc to next point
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

draw();
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600", height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, the coordinate system gets deformed when you define canvas dimensions in CSS. Use either inline styling (as I've done) or code it into your JS. For the arc you need, use ctx.arcTo(x1, x2, y1, y2, r), where x1, y1 is the point you are arcing around (440, 400 in your case) and x2,y2 is where you want the arc to meet back up with your figure, r is the radius.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arcto.asp

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(500, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(441.2, 392);
    ctx.arcTo(440, 400, 431.2, 402, 8);
 ctx.lineTo(0, 500);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#008AFF";
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas height="600" id="canvas" width="600"></canvas>
```