# How to draw line between points using click event handler?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using a event handler on a HTML canvas to track the coordinates of where a user clicks, and my idea is to connect coordinates together with a line.

The code below creates an Array and keeps a list of coordinates within the canvas element that the user has clicked on, and also contains logic to draw a line between the currently clicked point and the point that's  been previously clicked on.

The problem I'm encountering is that, no matter how many times I click, even though my Array is being populated with coordinates, the lines are not being drawn between the points.

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong, or if there is some re-rendering being done that might be wiping away the drawings I make on the canvas.

```js
var coords = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var coord = { "x": event.screenX, "y": event.screenY };
    document.getElementById("coords").innerText = "{" + coord.x + ", " + coord.y + "}";
    coords.push(coord);
    var max = coords.length - 1;
    if (typeof coords[max - 1] !== "undefined") {
        var curr = coords[max], prev = coords[max - 1];
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
        context.lineTo(curr.x, curr.y);
        context.stroke();
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
</html>
<head>
    <title>Drawing canvas</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id='coords'></p>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: might be because you're using a new context for each line

Comment: try declaring ctx after canvas, instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your context outside the click event and use canvas coordinates instead of screen one: `event.x` and `event.y`
Do not use CSS dimensions for the canvas. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

```js
var coords = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var coord = { "x": event.x, "y": event.y};
    document.getElementById("coords").innerText = "{" + coord.x + ", " + coord.y + "}";
    coords.push(coord);
    var max = coords.length - 1;
    if (typeof coords[max - 1] !== "undefined") {
        var curr = coords[max], prev = coords[max - 1];
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
        context.lineTo(curr.x, curr.y);
        context.stroke();
    }
});
```

```html
    <style>
        canvas {     
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
    </style>

   
    <canvas id='canvas' width="200" height="200"></canvas>
     <p id='coords'></p>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you set the `body` css?

Comment: It is optional. You need take a look at your webpage and determine styling by yourself.

Comment: Ah, I  see. Also, how did you wrap your code into a snippet like that?