# Changing an image size

Tags: javascript, image

I can't figure out how to change the format of an image. I'm trying to make the Dino Game from Google Chrome. And changing the image size won't work.

My code:

```
window.onload = function() {
var cvs = document.getElementById("gameArea");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var dino;
var obst = [];

function drawDino() {
    var dinoImg = new Image();
    dinoImg.src = 'dino.png';
    dinoImg.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(dinoImg, 0, 0);
        this.style.width = 100;
        this.style.height = 100;
    }
}

function drawObst() {

}

function draw() {
    drawDino();
    drawObst();
}

function startGame() {
    setInterval(draw,50);
}

startGame();
}
```

Comment: have you tried : `ctx.drawImage(dinoImg, x, y, width, height);` ?

Comment: `this.style.width` is only setting the style size of the canvas, not the actual size of the canvas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties

Comment: You are missing an unit like `px` in `this.style.width = 100;` & the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameters of [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) for resizing the image.

```
void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var cvs = document.getElementById("gameArea");
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

    var dino;
    var obst = [];

    function drawDino() {
        var dinoImg = new Image();
        dinoImg.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'; //'dino.png';
        dinoImg.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(dinoImg, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    }

    function drawObst() {

    }

    function draw() {
        drawDino();
        drawObst();
    }

    function startGame() {
        setInterval(draw,1000);
    }

    startGame();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameArea"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for.
You did not pass width & height parameters to drawIamge
`ctx.drawImage(dinoImg, x, y, width, height);`

Read more at: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var cvs = document.getElementById("gameArea");
 var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

 var dino;
 var obst = [];

 function drawDino() {
  var dinoImg = new Image();
  dinoImg.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/HeGEEbu.jpg';
  dinoImg.onload = function() {
     //ctx.drawImage(dinoImg, 0, 0);
     let width = 200;
     let height = 200;
     ctx.drawImage(dinoImg, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
 }

 function drawObst() {

 }

 function draw() {
  drawDino();
  drawObst();
 }

 function startGame() {
  setInterval(draw,50);
 }

 startGame();
}
```

```css
#gameArea {
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="gameArea" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
 </body>

</html>
```