# Width and Height in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I was using Chart.js and found that it recognizes the following two `style`s differently—`<canvas style="">` works well, while `<style>canvas{}` distorts the charts. Here're two examples.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<canvas id=Figure1 style="width:640px;height:480px"></canvas>

<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js></script>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("Figure1"),{type:"scatter",data:{datasets:[{data:[{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:3}]}]},options:{responsive:false}});
</script>
</html>
```

This code doesn't twist the image, so I wanted to apply the settings globally with the code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<style>canvas{width:640px;height:480px}</style>

<canvas id=Figure1></canvas>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js></script>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("Figure1"),{type:"scatter",data:{datasets:[{data:[{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:3}]}]},options:{responsive:false}});
</script>
</html>
```

I just relocated `width:640px;height:480px` in this code, but it stretches the image weirdly. Must I always use `<canvas style="">` to resize the Chart.js images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to specify the canvas' height and width. But what's the difference between the two methods you tried? Well, the full explanation can be found here 
[Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

P.S You can make the chart responsive by having responsive: true and putting your canvas inside a div. That way, the canvas will always take its container's dimensions.

```js
let line_chart = document.getElementById("line-chart");

    new Chart(line_chart, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
      datasets: [{ 
            label: 'Sample Data',
            data: [{ x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }] }],
      },
    options: {
      responsive:true,
    }
  });
```

```css
/* If you change the wrapper's height and width, the chart will follow the wrapper's dimensions */
.wrapper{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
</div>
```