# Canvas border increases the area, draw the border inside the canvas

Tags: css

How to put the border inside the canvas, so it is not expanded by the border:

```html
<canvas width="50" height="50" style="border: 10px solid black"></canvas>



is much bigger than 

<canvas width="50" height="50" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

`box-sizing: border-box;` doesn't help in this case

Please not that the canvas I am using is rectangular and its shape is not controlled via JavaScript.

Comment: box-shadow maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/ypqao8d2/

Comment: have u tried it..? ----> style = "outline: black 3px solid;"

Comment: @KiranMistry

Thanks, It works! I will go for it - no JS no unnecessary magic

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-shadow` in this case if you want to set the `width` & `height` by attribute.

```css
#canvas1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #000;
   box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #000;
}

#canvas2 {
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #000;
   box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: I've set them using attributes

Comment: They're different, do it necessary to set the width/height via attribute?

Comment: @JaredChu it's necessary to set width/height via attribute because the CSS one will simply distort the canvas; https://stackoverflow.com/q/2588181/8620333

Comment: I've updated my answer