# Script not loading css properties from external file

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

here are my 2 files

HTML:

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id=myCanvas></canvas>

    <script>
      var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      alert(c.width)
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
  width:480;
  height:360;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

Clearly, the width of my canvas element would be 480, but for some reason, `alert(c.width)` returns 300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because `c.width` refers to the element's width attribute. If that attribute is not present in the canvas element, you'll get the default value for it, which is 300px. The same would happen for height (150px).

To get the real canvas width, you can use `getBoundingClientRect()`. Also, don't forget to add 'px' after your CSS numeric values for width and height.

```css
canvas {
  width: 480px;
  height: 360px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id=myCanvas></canvas>

    <script>
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      alert(c.getBoundingClientRect().width)
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this does return 480 like expected, I am still having an issue where draw methods still think the canvas is 300x150, with the canvas rendering stretched to 480x360. Would there be any way to fix this problem too?

Comment: In this case, you must use the width and height attributes. That's because "`width` and `height` attributes determine the width or height of the canvas's coordinate system, whereas the CSS properties just determine the size of the box in which it will be shown", as from SamB's answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `c.offsetWidth` instead of `c.width`. As @BrunoSdoukos has already mentioned `width` in the context of how you are trying to use it requires that you set the width as an attribute on the `<canvas>` element, like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480"></canvas>
```

Because there isn't a width attribute set on the HTML element itself, using `c.width` will return the default width, which is 300px.

Because you have specified the element's width using CSS in order to get the elements width in this case you should use:

```
c.offsetWidth
```

Here is what MDN says about HTMLElement.offsetWidth:

> Typically, offsetWidth is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS width, including any borders, padding, and vertical scrollbars (if rendered). It does not include the width of pseudo-elements such as ::before or ::after.

You can ready more about this property here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth