# what is the right way to set html5 canvas tag size and why?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.style.width = 750+"px";
canvas.style.height = 250+"px";

OR

canvas.width = 750;
canvas.height = 250;
```

I just want to know which is the right way to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

Comment: The `style` values will only set the presentation size (CSS) stretching whatever the actual size of the canvas is, the `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` ones will set the size of your canvas buffer, where you'll draw. In the absence of a CSS rule, the presentation size will also be set to the canvas's size.