# html/css canvas width/height handling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i'm trying to code snake as a browsergame in javascript for a school project and i want to do it with an external .js file - not just in the .html.
my problem now is: when i call the main function in my html body, only the canvas gets modified by my script, not the snakeparts.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Snake - The Browser Game</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='main()'>
        <canvas id="gameCanvas">
            
        </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="snake.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
#gameCanvas {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

snake.js:

```
const board_border = 'black';
const board_background = "white";
const snake_col = 'lightblue';
const snake_border = 'darkblue';

const snakeboard = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
const snakeboard_ctx = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');

let snake = [{x: 200, y: 200}, {x: 190, y: 200}, {x: 180, y: 200}, {x: 170, y: 200}, {x: 160, y: 200}]

function main(){
    clearCanvas();
    drawSnake();
}

function clearCanvas(){
    snakeboard_ctx.fillStyle = board_background;
    snakeboard_ctx.strokestyle = board_border;
    snakeboard_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, snakeboard.width, snakeboard.height);
    snakeboard_ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, snakeboard.width, snakeboard.height);
}

function drawSnake(){
   snake.forEach(drawSnakeparts);
}

function drawSnakeparts(snakePart){
    snakeboard.fillStyle = snake_col;
    snakeboard.strokeStyle = snake_border;
    snakeboard_ctx.fillRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);  
    snakeboard_ctx.strokeRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);
}
```

i'm fairly new to all that stuff, couldn't find the answer after a lot of googling and asking gpt...

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You have no `<script>` tag that loads the JS file, unless you named it `jquery.js`, which is very confusing (that's usually the name of the jQuery library).

Comment: Sadly no errors in the console (check with CTRL+SHIFT+J would show me immediately?) - and thanks for the input with jquery, i've change the name of my .js file to "snake.js", which fits better for this purpose - but yes, the jquery.js was the js file, that i've shown in the above post.

Comment: It's calling `drawSnake()`, so the problem is that drawing the snake parts doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, comments below fixed it - canvas width had to be set in html, not css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the width/height of the canvas. If you do not specify them, the default is 300x150. And since your snake is positioned at y:200 it is out of the visible area.

Read [HTMLCanvasElement: width property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) and [HTMLCanvasElement: height property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height)

Use

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it - i was setting the width and height in my style.css. 
also makes sense, why this wouldn't work - cause the html loads the javascript and then would have to load the css file aswell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-attributes

Comment: i see, thank you - that makes more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Your entire snake is out of canvas, because your canvas is 300x150

You have to change canvas width and height through attributes

Changing styles will only stretch the current pixels

```js
const board_border = 'black';
const board_background = "white";
const snake_col = 'lightblue';
const snake_border = 'darkblue';

const snakeboard = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
const snakeboard_ctx = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');

let snake = [{
  x: 200,
  y: 200
}, {
  x: 190,
  y: 200
}, {
  x: 180,
  y: 200
}, {
  x: 170,
  y: 200
}, {
  x: 160,
  y: 200
}]

main()

function main() {
  clearCanvas();
  drawSnake();
}

function clearCanvas() {
  snakeboard_ctx.fillStyle = board_background;
  snakeboard_ctx.strokestyle = board_border;
  snakeboard_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, snakeboard.width, snakeboard.height);
  snakeboard_ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, snakeboard.width, snakeboard.height);
}

function drawSnake() {
  snake.forEach(drawSnakeparts);
}

function drawSnakeparts(snakePart) {
  snakeboard.fillStyle = snake_col;
  snakeboard.strokeStyle = snake_border;
  snakeboard_ctx.fillRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);
  snakeboard_ctx.strokeRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);
}
```

```css
#gameCanvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! Comment above fixed it aswell - thank you for your time.