# HTML Canvas is really low-definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas, tailwind-css

I am currently building a web app where it would be useful to have the functionnality of a HTML canvas. The problem is that, whenever I try to render things, it's really pixelated.

[The results I'm getting from the canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0FFq.png)

I am using Next JS, TypeScript and TailwindCSS.

Here is my code for now:

My canvas component:

```
"use client"

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"

export default function MainView() {

  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

  // main display of the canvas
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) throw new Error("no canvas ref")

    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d")

    if (!context) throw new Error("unable to get canvas context")

    context.beginPath()
    context.roundRect(10, 10, 100, 100, 20)
    context.fill()
  }, [])

  return <div className="w-full h-full">
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} className="w-full h-full">
    </canvas>
  </div>
}
```

globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --light-color: #f3f3f3;
  --medium-light-color: #efefef;
  --dark-color: #0e0e0e;
  --highlight-color: #336dff;
  --slate-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--medium-light-color);
  color: var(--dark-color);
}

canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

Originally, the image was really blurry, so I added `image-rendering: pixelated;` in the globals.css file.

That removed the blur, but there is still a really low resolution.

Comment: You have to change the resolution of the canvas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with \`width\` & \`height\` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-attributes)

Comment: So, I have to set the width and height to actual numbers?

Comment: You have to change `width` and `height` attributes, not style

Comment: Oh. Ok. Thank you. I'll try changing that.

Comment: @Konrad It worked, thank you very much!