# Size of HTML5 Canvas via CSS versus element attributes

Tags: css, html, canvas

I don't get why the following pieces of code produce different results, because css would scale the canvas as it was zoomed in,

```
<style>
#canvas {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
</style>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

In contrast with this approach (that works as expected):

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "because css would scale the canvas as it was zoomed in"? Cheers!

Comment: Yes, when you apply the css styling, the canvas fits 800x600 but the content inside it is "enlarged", it's like the canvas coordinate system keeps it's default size, but is "stretched". Let me know if I'm not clear enought. I'm using Firefox 4.0b11

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977741/resizable-canvas-jquery-ui/2042935

Comment: Note that the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas should not have dimensions (unlike CSS). You should have `width="800"`, not `width="800px"`.

Comment: s/dimensions/explicit pixel units/

Comment: This question is also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24608862/687677

Comment: @Phrogz why shouldn't it be specified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

Comment: une explication claire , précise...et fondamentale ! : https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The explanation is here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width as seen in another post, thanks!

> The intrinsic dimensions of the canvas element equal the size of the coordinate space, with the numbers interpreted in CSS pixels. However, the element can be sized arbitrarily by a style sheet. **During rendering, the image is scaled to fit this layout size**.

Comment: That is the most useful answer I have seen on how the canvas coordinate system works.

Answer (score 74):

Think about what happens if you have a JPG that *is* 32x32 (it has exactly 1024 total pixels) but specify via CSS that it should *appear* as `width:800px; height:16px`. The same thing applies to HTML Canvas:

- The `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas element itself decide how many pixels you can draw on. If you don't specify the height and width of the canvas element, then [per the specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width):
  *"the width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150."*
- The `width` and `height` CSS properties control the size that the element displays on screen. If the CSS dimensions are not set, the intrinsic size of the element is used for layout.

If you specify in CSS a different size than the actual dimensions of the canvas it must be stretched and squashed by the browser as necessary for display. You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/9bheb/5/

Comment: @Phrogz's answer is clearer than the accepted answer. A canvas with pixel dimensions specified by its `height` and `width` HTML attributes (or the default 300x150) will be scaled to the size specified by CSS properties.

Comment: @Phrogz this seems to be the correct answer in my opinion.

Comment: As an addition here is what I am using so that the canvas takes it's size from CSS. The `substring` is to remove the `px` from the end of the string 

    `const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"); 
    const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(canvas); 
    canvas.width = compStyles.width.substr(0, compStyles.width.length - 2);
    canvas.height = compStyles.height.substr(0, compStyles.height.length - 2);`

Comment: What if I want to change the _actual_ size of the canvas when the browser is resized?

Comment: @RonInbar The add an event listener for the resize event, and set the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas element to match the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties showing its actual size. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8686566/405017 http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas-fullscreen.html

Answer (score -4):

The best way to size your canvas is to include in a div and style your div with the size that you want.

Here is the CSS

```
<style>
#divCanvas{
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="divCanvas">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```