# Scale HTML canvas to browser window size but don't scale elements within the canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there a way to scale your HTML canvas to the browser window width/height but not scale the contents within it? Say I was creating Asteroids and want to use the entire browser window but don't want the rocks and ship to scale up/down when I resize the window.

Comment: asteroids, rocks and ship.. wut?

Comment: +1 for a good question. I believe I have the answer you need.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Do not use CSS to scale your canvas. That will scale the pixels in the canvas up/down.
2. Instead, watch for a `resize` event on an appropriate element (e.g. the window) and then change the `.width` and `.height` properties of the canvas appropriately in JavaScript. This will change how many pixels you are drawing with.
3. Continue to use the same fixed-size drawing commands you always use. Object will stay that same pixel size on screen.
4. To keep your contents centered on the screen, you may want to treat 0,0 as the center of the canvas by using `translate()` on the context right after you resize it. For example:

   ```
   var ctx = document.querySelector('#mycanvas').getContext('2d');
   window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
     var width  = calculateDesiredWidth();  // your code here
     var height = calculateDesiredHeight(); // your code here
     ctx.canvas.width  = width;
     ctx.canvas.height = height;
     ctx.translate(width/2,height/2); // now 0,0 is the center of the canvas.
   },false);
   ```

### Full working example: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas-fullscreen.html

Comment: +1 : you're really an awesome guy .. keep it up .. Happy New Year :)

Comment: Phrogz, thanks so much for the answer and the working example. That helps tremendously!