# jquery floating canvas plugin

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

i visited this website recently http://www.consumerbarometer.com and attracted by its design. I try to look for the same kind of jquery plugin, but not luck. i found this eventually, http://blog.hostgrenade.com/2012/04/25/html5-canvas-bubble-demo-v2/ but it's still not the similar.

does anyone know is there any similar jquery plugin?

thanks in advanced!

Comment: I doubt you will find a jQuery plugin dealing with this, as jQuery does nothing with canvas.

Comment: canvas can be done using a single HTML5 code. but what if is animated canvas like the example website shown?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plug-in, you just need a [full-screen canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684820/scale-html-canvas-to-browser-window-size-but-dont-scale-elements-within-the-can) positioned behind the content that you can draw animated circles on with colors that you pick.
<sup>*Note: the answer on that page happens to be mine.*</sup>

Is there a particular part of that which you were hoping the plug-in would take care of for you?

Indeed, there's no reason that this even needs to be a `<canvas>`, as you could produce the same effect with animated positioned `<img>` elements that were low opacity. The only 'tricky' part would be placing them in a container with `overflow:hidden` so that no scrollbars appear as the content moves off the edge of the screen.

Comment: thx phrogz. if i wanna do the exactly same effect like the website for example magnify the circle canvas when rollover, is there any jquery plugin available? or it can be down easily using js ? p.s:i am a beginner in js.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use jQuery, you can use [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). It doesn't use canvas but you can do similar things. Otherwise you can look at Javascript canvas librairies ([see this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938969/current-state-of-javascript-canvas-libraries2012)) like FabricJS or KineticJS.

PS: like said Phrogz, you don't need a plugin. You just have to use a "modern browser"