# HTML5 canvas perform inconsistent when define its width and height using ID selector

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My html file is very simple:

```
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
<button onclick="DrawSVG()">Draw SVG</button>
</body>
```

When click the button I draw the SVG on the canvas, using canvg.js

```
var opts = {
  ignoreMouse: false,
  ignoreClear: true,
  ignoreDimensions : true,
  offsetX: 0,
  offsetY: 0
};
canvg(canvas, "face.svg", opts);
```

face.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >
<rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="80" rx="6" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-
width="1px" fill-opacity="0.7" />
</svg>
```

It seems correct.

But when I define the width and height in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
#canvas {
width: 900px;
height: 400px;
}
```

The svg on the canvas is 4 times larger than before. What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of HTML5 Canvas via CSS versus element attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034529/size-of-html5-canvas-via-css-versus-element-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width

> The intrinsic dimensions of the canvas element equal the size of the
>   coordinate space, with the numbers interpreted in CSS pixels. However,
>   the element can be sized arbitrarily by a style sheet. **During
>   rendering, the image is scaled to fit this layout size.**

(I borrowed this from [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034529/size-of-html5-canvas-via-css-versus-element-attributes) because it's worth repeating.)