# Canvas element, draw circle resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am SLOWLY trying to create the breakout game to get more familiar with javascript.
I am trying to re size the canvas element according to the window size, but notice the 
circle I am rendering re sizes automatically according to the size of the canvas.  How would i render the size of the circle independently from the size of the canvas?

```
//resize canvas
$(function(){
$("#canvas").width($(window).width());
});

//get a reference to the canvas
var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

//draw a circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(75, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

here is my fiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/z25q7/3/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change the canvas' `width` property directly, not its CSS `style.width` (which is what jQuery does):

```
$("#canvas")[0].width = $(window).width();
```

More information here: [Size of HTML5 Canvas via CSS versus element attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034529/size-of-html5-canvas-via-css-versus-element-attributes)