# Layered HTML5 Canvases Height/Width Resetting to 300x150px

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am attempting to layer two canvases, so that one has a background image and the other can have a different image on it. When I layer them in, the width and height resets to the default 300x150px of a canvas instead of respecting the width/height I put in. The canvas with the id of 'c' is my top layer

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="position:relative; border:1px solid">
                <canvas id="b" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:1; width:640px; height:429px;"></canvas>
                <canvas id="c" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:2; width:640px; height:429px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

I am using fabric.js to create the canvases as follows:

```
var canvasb = new fabric.Canvas('b');
canvasb.setBackgroundImage('imgs/mybackgroundimage.png', canvasb.renderAll.bind(canvasb));

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can set the width and height inside the *style* section, why dont you try this way instead:

```
<canvas id="b" width="640" height="429" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:1;"></canvas>
```

(Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

Also, this reference might be useful for the distinction between setting the size via attribute and CSS:

[Size of HTML5 Canvas via CSS versus element attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034529/size-of-html5-canvas-via-css-versus-element-attributes)

Comment: I tried this, but the instead of overlaying the canvases are stacking. Here is the current code:

     <div style="position:relative; border:1px solid">
            <canvas id="b" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:1;" width="640px" height="429px"></canvas>
            <canvas id="c" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:2;" width="640px" height="429px"></canvas>
        </div>

Comment: It seems to work in its own page, but I am running bootstrap and wondering if there is a conflict on the page with bootstrap